# view parents' class members in netbeans navigator?

Tags: php, netbeans

in the navigator i can only see the current class' members.

is there a way to include the parents' members.

cause it is very useful when working with a framework, then you don't have to look for them in the documentation.

i think this is available in eclipse but not netbeans.

[netbeans navigator](http://i44.tinypic.com/34j9h5w.png)

Comment: you may want to include info about the version/bundle of NetBeans that  you are using.  It looks like you are using an older version... so an upgrade may resolve the issue.

Comment: no im using netbeans 6.8 and also netbeans 6.9. both are looking the  same. im on mac btw. maybe its not the same as in windows?

Comment: Ahh... it looks like you want info about the PHP support...  That is a bit different from the Java support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Netbeans 6.8, you can click on the icon of the two people (Show inherited members) to see the members/methods define in superclasses.

[image: wait... the image is loading]

^^^^^^ That is the button right there.

The navigator used for PHP code does not provide that feature.

[image]

^^^^^ Booo. No Show inherited members feature here....

Comment: hmm weird. my "footer" doesnt look like that. how do i show it?

Comment: Did you manage to find it? Or am i missing something else on v.6.9.1 (PHP specific)